# Lebesgue measure of union of a finite number of hyperplane and isolated points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: lebesgue-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Here a question for you guys. Let $S_1,S_2,\dots, S_l\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be some affine spaces of dimension $n-1$, and let $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_j\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be some points. Let $\mathcal{S}=\bigcup_{i=1}^l S_i$ and  $\mathcal{P}=\bigcup_{i=1}^j P_i$. I'd like to prove that the Lebesgue measure of $\mathcal{S}\cup\mathcal{P}=0$. My idea was to show that the Hausdorff dimension of $\mathcal{S}\cup\mathcal{P}$ is $n-1$, in that case the result would follow immediately. However, I am not sure whether for affine spaces the linear dimension coincides with the Hausdorff dimension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Much easier is to directly prove that a point and a hyperplane each have  Lebesgue measure zero.

A single point can be covered by boxes of decreasing radius approaching zero, whose volumes approach zero. Therefore, a single point has Lebesgue measure zero.

Next, an $n-1$ dimensional cube $Q$ contained in a hyperplane can be covered by a box of the form $Q \times J$, where $J$ is an interval of any length in a perpendicular line to the hyperplane. By letting $\text{Length}(J)$ approach zero, the volumes of these boxes approach zero, so the Lebesgue measure of an $n-1$ dimensional cube contained in a hyperplane equals zero.

Next, an $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane is a countable unit of $n-1$ dimensional unit cubes, so the Lebesgue measure of a hyperplane equals zero.

Finally, any finite (or countable) union of sets of Lebesgue measure zero has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Thanks for replying, your proof sounds interesting. The only point I am missing is the last sentence, i.e, that the ''any finite (or countable) union of sets of Lebesgue measure zero has Lebesgue measure zero'', could you please provide me with a reference on that point? Thanks!

Comment: @frank This property of Lebesgue measure is called countable (sub-)additivity and is well-known, any book that treats Lebesgue measure will discuss it (or google it). Say $A=\cup_n A_n$ where each $A_n$, $n=1,2,3,...$, has measure $0$, and you want to cover $A$ by an open set of measure $\varepsilon>0$. Since each $A_n$ is of Lebesgue measure $0$, cover $A_n$ with on open set $U_n$ of measure $\frac\varepsilon{2^n}$. Then $A=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$, and the latter has measure at most $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac\varepsilon{2^n}=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am only finding results on countable (sub-)additivity about outer measures. Could you point me a reference on that? I'd be grateful!

Comment: You will find that in practically any book on Real Analysis.